# Spring 3 MVC, multipart form and controller mapping issue

Tags: spring, controller, multipart

My application uses submit name as action name consistently. It has worked so far.

Enter multipart form...

**html**

```
<form:form modelAttribute="screenObject" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="save"  value="Save" type="submit" />
```

**Controller**

```
public static final String ACTION_SAVE="save";
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, params=ACTION_SAVE)
public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute("screenObject") FileHeaderEditScreenObject screenObject, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, Locale locale) {
```

**Error**

```
message Request method 'POST' not supported
```

If I remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, control flows right into the `save` method. I do need different actions on this multipart form. I want to stay consitent so I hope I do not have to introduce any hidden fields to represent actions or submit the form to different urls...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to remove `params=ACTION_SAVE` from the annotation. 
It look like that it doesn't parse submit action from a multipart request.

You can handle that parameter as a request parameter:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, params=ACTION_SAVE)
public ModelAndView save(
   @RequestParam(value = "submit", required = true) String action,
   @ModelAttribute("screenObject") ....

{
     switch (action) {
        case "action1": ...
        case "action2": ...
     }
}
```

This is not very nice. I would just use different URLs like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/action1"})
    public void action1(

@RequestMapping("/action2"})
    public void action2(
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I have multiple actions for this controller to handle. One controller method per action. `params=ACTION_SAVE` needs to stay or it's: Spring MVC is useless.

Comment: See my updated. I have been always using the second approach - which works perfectly.